# Pandas: Querying an object column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame

```
           Q1  Q2_1  Q2_2 respid   Value      Q2
        0   1     1     0      1     [1]     [1]
        1   2     0     1      2     [2]     [2]
        2   3     0     1      3     [2]     [2]
        3   4     1     0      4     [1]     [1]
        4   5     1     1      5  [1, 2]  [1, 2]
        5   1     0     0      6      []      []
        6   1     1     1      7  [1, 2]  [1, 2]
        7   3     0     0      8      []      []
```

I can query columns with single values like df[df['Q1']==1].
However I cannot do df[1 in df['Q2']].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use apply for that:

```
df[df['Q2'].apply(lambda x : 1 in x)]
```

Comment: Thanks man - also is there a way to write  custom function where i can pass in a function into the data frame and get rows for matching criteria..

Something like
`**df[filter("Q2",1)]**`

Where filter is the custom function

Comment: Yes, that is what apply does. df[df['Q2'].apply(your_custom_function)]. You pass a function into the **column** of the data frame and get rows for matching criteria.